# Converting MS-Word 2003 equations to MS-Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

I have a document that has been written in MS Word 2003, and contains equations and other....

Now I want to convert it to MS Word 2007 format but the equations are in the old format (MS Equation Editor 3.0).

How can I convert all equations to the new format?

Comment: how are you doing the conversion ?

Comment: by ms word and using save as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GrindEq offers a [MathType-to-Word-Equation](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=mathtype2equation) converter, it seems to do a proper job converting MathType or MS Equation Editor equations to the new format. Shareware.

Answer (score 0):

equations in '03 are structurally different from those in '07. You cannot convert one from other. You have to redesign those in '07.

[see here](http://www.lut.ac.uk/it/office2007/equations.html)