# Convert MathType equations to native Word 2007/2010 equations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, equations, equation-editor

Is it possible to convert equations typeset with MathType to native Office 2007/2010 equations? MathType doesn't seem to have that option, but I need it to parse LaTeX formulae in my Word document.

As MathType is a better equation editor, from [this related question](https://superuser.com/q/357122/99136) I get the feeling that this is not possible at all. Did anybody get this working, perhaps with an external tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that GrindEq offers a [MathType-to-Word-Equation](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=mathtype2equation) converter, it seems to do a proper job. Shareware.

Comment: It seems that GrindEq is not free, Is there any free software?

Answer (score 2):

MathType has a *toggle TeX* feature that's convenient for converting a single equation or small selection of equations either from MathType to LaTeX or vice versa. There's also the *Convert Equations* command on the **MathType Ribbon** in Word that gives you more conversion options.

Comment: My problem with MathType is that I have been unable to make it output *native Word equations* instead of MathType objects.

Answer (score 2):

this way works converting from mathtype version 7... to ms word 2016:

1. double click on equation and open it within mathtype editor.
2. go: preferences > cut and copy preferences
3. click: MathML or TeX
4. select: MathML 2.0 (namespace attr) from dropdown list
5. click ok
6. select equation and copy
7. paste into ms word (select "Create an OMML equation" if a pop up appears)
8. Thats all, I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

GrindEq does do a proper job, but in its free state, you get only 10 product launches. There is a much longer and manual process, which is outlined in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzg-wZW4vrY.

1. Basically, you open the equation in MathType
2. Copy whole of it as LaTeX (in MathType, Preferences -> Cut and Copy Preferences -> Choose MathML or TeX -> Select LaTeX 2.09 or later from the drop down and uncheck Include MathType data in translation)
3. Paste it in a conversion site like https://www.mathtowebonline.com and click convert
4. Copy the generated MathML and paste in Word. It will render as a Word 20xx Equation.